# Definition for tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I want to write code in Typescript that generates a `tsconfig.json` file from a runtime object. Where can I get the definition for this object, e.g. something like the following:

```
interface TSConfig [
    compileOnSave?: boolean;
    files?: string[];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source base you can finde some typings for CompilerOptions https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts#L2305 , TypeAcquisition https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts#L2379 and an interface that they use after they has parsed a tsconfig.json https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts#L2434

On json.schemastore there exists a schema for tsconfig.json: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

On the offical website there is a description for tsconfig: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Based on them I created this:

```
interface MapLike<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}

enum ModuleResolutionKind {
    Classic = 1,
    NodeJs = 2,
}

interface CompilerOptions {
    allowJs?: boolean;
    allowSyntheticDefaultImports?: boolean;
    allowUnreachableCode?: boolean;
    allowUnusedLabels?: boolean;
    alwaysStrict?: boolean;
    baseUrl?: string;
    charset?: string;
    checkJs?: boolean;
    declaration?: boolean;
    emitDeclarationOnly?: boolean;
    declarationDir?: string;
    disableSizeLimit?: boolean;
    downlevelIteration?: boolean;
    emitBOM?: boolean;
    emitDecoratorMetadata?: boolean;
    experimentalDecorators?: boolean;
    forceConsistentCasingInFileNames?: boolean;
    importHelpers?: boolean;
    inlineSourceMap?: boolean;
    inlineSources?: boolean;
    isolatedModules?: boolean;
    jsx?: JsxEmit;
    lib?: string[];
    locale?: string;
    mapRoot?: string;
    maxNodeModuleJsDepth?: number;
    module?: ModuleKind;
    moduleResolution?: ModuleResolutionKind;
    newLine?: NewLineKind;
    noEmit?: boolean;
    noEmitHelpers?: boolean;
    noEmitOnError?: boolean;
    noErrorTruncation?: boolean;
    noFallthroughCasesInSwitch?: boolean;
    noImplicitAny?: boolean;
    noImplicitReturns?: boolean;
    noImplicitThis?: boolean;
    noStrictGenericChecks?: boolean;
    noUnusedLocals?: boolean;
    noUnusedParameters?: boolean;
    noImplicitUseStrict?: boolean;
    noLib?: boolean;
    noResolve?: boolean;
    out?: string;
    outDir?: string;
    outFile?: string;
    paths?: MapLike<string[]>;
    preserveConstEnums?: boolean;
    preserveSymlinks?: boolean;
    project?: string;
    reactNamespace?: string;
    jsxFactory?: string;
    removeComments?: boolean;
    rootDir?: string;
    rootDirs?: string[];
    skipLibCheck?: boolean;
    skipDefaultLibCheck?: boolean;
    sourceMap?: boolean;
    sourceRoot?: string;
    strict?: boolean;
    strictFunctionTypes?: boolean;
    strictNullChecks?: boolean;
    strictPropertyInitialization?: boolean;
    suppressExcessPropertyErrors?: boolean;
    suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors?: boolean;
    target?: ScriptTarget;
    traceResolution?: boolean;
    types?: string[];
    /** Paths used to compute primary types search locations */
    typeRoots?: string[];
    esModuleInterop?: boolean;
}

interface TypeAcquisition {
    enableAutoDiscovery?: boolean;
    enable?: boolean;
    include?: string[];
    exclude?: string[];
    [option: string]: string[] | boolean | undefined;
}

enum ModuleKind {
    None = 0,
    CommonJS = 1,
    AMD = 2,
    UMD = 3,
    System = 4,
    ES2015 = 5,
    ESNext = 6,
}
enum JsxEmit {
    None = 0,
    Preserve = 1,
    React = 2,
    ReactNative = 3,
}
enum NewLineKind {
    CarriageReturnLineFeed = 0,
    LineFeed = 1,
}

enum ScriptTarget {
    ES3 = 0,
    ES5 = 1,
    ES2015 = 2,
    ES2016 = 3,
    ES2017 = 4,
    ES2018 = 5,
    ESNext = 6,
    Latest = 6,
}

interface TsConfig {
    compilerOptions: CompilerOptions;
    exclude: string[];
    compileOnSave: boolean;
    extends: string;
    files: string[];
    include: string[];
    typeAcquisition: TypeAcquisition
}
```

Comment: If I would write such an interface by hand, I would replace the various `enum`s with the union types of their values: e.g. `newLine?: 'cr' | 'lf';` instead of `NewLineKind`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse some of the types defined in the typescript module (you can get it via `npm install typescript`) for compiler options and type acquisition options, although there is no type defined for the full tsconfig.json, and we need to do some conditional type magic (available in typescript 2.8) to get the type for compiler options. The enums are exported, so you can just use them directly.

```
import * as ts from 'typescript' // Import will be elided as long as we only use types from it, so we don't have the compiler code  loaded at runtime

type CompilerOptions = typeof ts.parseCommandLine extends (...args: any[])=> infer TResult ? 
    TResult extends { options: infer TOptions } ? TOptions : never : never;
type TypeAcquisition = typeof ts.parseCommandLine extends (...args: any[])=> infer TResult ? 
    TResult extends { typeAcquisition?: infer TTypeAcquisition } ? TTypeAcquisition : never : never;

interface TsConfig {

    compilerOptions: CompilerOptions;
    exclude: string[];
    compileOnSave: boolean;
    extends: string;
    files: string[];
    include: string[];
    typeAcquisition: TypeAcquisition
}
```

**Note** This has the advantage that changes made to the `CompilerOptions` and `TypeAcquisition` types by the compiler team will be reflected in your code when you update the package. The disadvantage is that it extracts some types from the compiler API which probably were not directly exposed for a reason (although since they are part of the result of `ts.parseCommandLine` if the compiler team would change them, it would be a breaking API change)

Comment: I think you meant to answer this on a different question.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Yes, i posted to the wrong question sorry. I meant to answer yours as well, but only got to it now, updated the answer.